# How to read the content of a variable in a for loop in MATLAB?

Tags: arrays, matlab, for-loop, variables

I am running a script that creates a matrix from a data file called epsi.resu, the file is then converted to a text file. I have multiple files epsi_value1_value2.resu where the number ranges from 20 to 58 for the first value and from 20 to 28 for the second value. I would like to do this process in a for loop. This is what I tried:

```
for i = 20:2:26
for j = 20:2:28

epsi = importfile1('epsi_i_j.resu', 6, 9);
writetable(epsi,'epsi_i_j.txt','Delimiter',' ');
type 'epsi.resu';

end
end
```

Unfortunately this produces an error "invalid file identifier"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is because 'epsi_i_j.resu' is a constant string

if i worth 0 and j 0 it still try to read 'epsi_i_j.resu' and not 'epsi_0_0.resu' 
i'm not sure of the syntaxe but try something like

```
epsi = importfile1( ['epsi_' num2str(i) '_' num2str(j) '.resu'],6,9)
```